# events 'missing'

Tags: wordpress, civievent

someone of our team managing the events in civiCRM yesterday realized that there are events missing from the the 'manage events' page in our wordpress installation (4.7.31)

in researching i found this
[Events 'missing' after upgrade to 4.7.19](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18516/events-missing-after-upgrade-to-4-7-19)
which very much looked like the issue, but the quick fix of updating CRM/Event/BAO/event.php didn't change anything so i just updated to 5.2.0 as i assumed this should fix it.

unfortunately the events in question are still not shown.

Checking contacts who had been participants in one of these events does show the event listed there and i can get a list of all participants - but i can't manage/edit/duplicate such event.

any hints on how to debug/resolve this?

thanks,
markus.

Comment: i think it's pretty likely permissions are involved - do you have a user with pretty much all permissions on the DB?

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to your DB you could look in civicrm_event and peruse the data there in case you have some odd values in eg date fields

otherwise try usual of clearing caches, drop templates_c folder etc etc in case the fix has worked but you just aren't seeing it

Comment: Or search for all events under manage event page.

Comment: well, searching was one of the obvious things that have been done first - but it doesn't deliver any results, even if using the exact event name.

Comment: chaches were cleared while updating, so this shouldn't be the issue. the event (i'm limiting my testing to one now even though there might be others) is in the DB with no obvious wonky data - using it's ID in a _&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fmanage%2Fsettings&reset=1&action=update&id=_ url i can access and configure it fine. it's - as expected - just not displayed or found in the overviews :(

Comment: not sure what else to suggest without being able to poke my nose around your system. do new events you create show up fine?

Comment: any chance new Permissions are involved (wild thinking now)

Comment: @markusk you might need to check if somehow `is_template` column is set to 1 for the id in `civicrm_event` table. Also try to check if any extension is involved or access this page as an admin user

Comment: thanks for the tips - @jitendra-fuzion but the is_template is set to zero as with all the others. the only extension i had installed was org.civicrm.vieweventparticipants which i once played with - just disabled - but didn't change anything.

Comment: yes @petednz-fuzion - new events show up fine, and there weren't really any changes permission-wise, there are just 3 admin users who manage (and debug ;)) this installation, which is the same since it's initial setup. also i can't narrow it down to any change that might have happened at a certain point of time as events before and after show up fine :/