# CiviCRM Update 4.7.27 Operation failed: Update Indices Errno: 150

Tags: upgrade, indices

I updated my CiviCRM version to 4.7.27 yesterday and got a Performance warning on my system status page that there are some Missing indices. Clicking the 'Update Indices' button doesn't fix the problem and gives an error:

```
Operation failed: Update Indices
DB Error: unknown error
Debug information:
DROP INDEX UI_case_contact_id ON civicrm_case_contact [nativecode=1025 ** Error on rename of './rmcivicrm/#sql-6a4_f3186b' to './rmcivicrm/civicrm_case_contact' (errno: 150)]
```

I'm using Civicrm in Wordpress 4.9. Anyone please enlighten me on how to solve this error?

Comment: This seems to be a known problem. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/problem-fixing-missing-indexes-after-upgrade-to-4-7 and https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21490/update-indices-fails-with-errno-150-on-drop-index-ui-case-contact-id-after-upgra