# CiviCRM 4.7.29 Update Indices fails

Tags: indices

I've messed around unsuccessfully to update indices by following various posts in StackExchange for similar errors. I have the impression that the Update Indices button simply does not work correctly.

If I push it at the moment, I get:

```
DB Error: already exists
Debug information:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_entity_id_entity_table_account_relationship ON civicrm_entity_financial_account (entity_id, entity_table, account_relationship) [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry '0-civicrm_financial_type-12' for key 'index_entity_id_entity_table_account_relationship']
```

Does anyone have a good way of removing all indices and recreating them?

I just upgraded from 4.7.25 to 4.7.29 (and am on the latest Wordpress version) if that is relevant.

Tried [CiviCRM Update 4.7.27 Operation failed: Update Indices Errno: 150](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21552/civicrm-update-4-7-27-operation-failed-update-indices-errno-150) but it didn't work either `(complained about ALTER table civicrm_option_value DROP INDEX index_option_group_id_name with #1091 - Can't DROP 'index_option_group_id_name'; check that column/key exists)`

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/problem-fixing-missing-indexes-after-upgrade-to-4-7/21102#21102) is the possible solution for this. Try running the sql queries through shell or phpmyadmin and than re-run the update indices.

Looking at the db error i can see civirm_entity_financial_account have duplicate rows. Please get rid of one row or all with entity_id = 0 as it doesn't make sense and then re-run update indices.

```
Delete civicrm_entity_financial_account where entity_id = 0 and entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type';
```

Comment: Okay. What error are you getting when you run update indices?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This is what happens: 

Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "civicrm_entity_financial_account" at position 7)
SQL query:

delete civicrm_entity_financial_account where entity_id = 0 and entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where entity_id = 0 and entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'' at line 1

Comment: I didn't re-run Update Indices yet

Comment: Deleted the unnecessary duplicate using SQL and the update ran through successfully. It took a bit of guts to push the delete button, but afterwards, it felt good!  ;-)

Thanks for the info!

Comment: My pleasure... Cheerz