# "Update indices" fails because of `foreign key constraint`

Tags: database, indices

A site that was running fine on 5.60.0 for a week or so with no notices. I see today that there is a notice about missing indices:

[image: screenshot of tables missing indices]

Ok. I can follow instructions. However on pressing the "Update indices" button I get an error pop-up:

`Operation failed: Update Indices DB Error: unknown error Debug information: DROP INDEX UI_case_contact_id ON civicrm_case_contact [nativecode=1553 ** Cannot drop index 'UI_case_contact_id': needed in a foreign key constraint]`

In poking around here on Stack Exchange I see issues related to the update indices process popping up, but they seem adjacent to my problem rather than the same. I am also struggling to make sense of their solutions, which seem very specific and none of which seem to involve a `foreign key constraint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't getting good hits on searching, but following re-links in comments on questions related to indices problems, I found this Question with an accepted answer that solved my problem:

[Problem fixing missing indexes after upgrade to 4.7](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/problem-fixing-missing-indexes-after-upgrade-to-4-7)