# Update 4.7.22 : Operation failed: Update Indices DB Error: already exists

Tags: error, database, upgrade

I'm just update to civicrm 4.7.22 on Drupal 7.56.

After the update, I received a system status warning "Performance warning: Missing indices".

I click to Update Indices and have these error: "Operation failed: Update Indices DB Error: already exists"

In the Drupal log, I have the message:

"$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => exceptionHandler ) [code] => -5 [message] => DB Error: already exists [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_case_contact_id ON civicrm_case_contact (case_id, contact_id) [nativecode=1061 ** Duplicate key name 'UI_case_contact_id'] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_case_contact_id ON civicrm_case_contact (case_id, contact_id) [nativecode=1061 ** Duplicate key name 'UI_case_contact_id'] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: already exists" code=-5 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UI_case_contact_id ON civicrm_case_contact (case_id, contact_id) [nativecode=1061 ** Duplicate key name 'UI_case_contact_id']"] )"

Do I need to solve this issue? And how can I?

Thanks.

Comment: There's an answer posted for this issue at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19384/how-can-i-fix-this-problem-with-duplicate-index-in-4-7-21/19385#19385

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix this problem with duplicate index in 4.7.21?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19384/how-can-i-fix-this-problem-with-duplicate-index-in-4-7-21)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of posts on this issue. The one that worked easiest for me is the artfulrobot answer in [How to find and/or fix missing indices?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/how-to-find-and-or-fix-missing-indices/19424#comment22161_19424). You can execute steps 3-5 runing SQL commands either at the command line or in phpMyAdmin. Although the post was for drupal, it worked for me on our wordpress instance.