# Where can I see the database upgrade script?

Tags: upgrade, database

I want to see which indices were supposed to be created in the last upgrade I ran because I get a status report message saying that some indices are missing, but when I click "Update Indices" I get an error saying "DB Error: already exists". So I'm pretty sure some of the indices are missing, but not all of them. So I want to manually create only the missing ones.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of other threads around this issue and you may find the specific advice you need if you read through them eg

[How to find and/or fix missing indices?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/how-to-find-and-or-fix-missing-indices)

or this one

[Missing indices status after upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.21 on WordPress 4.8](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19408/missing-indices-status-after-upgrading-to-civicrm-4-7-21-on-wordpress-4-8)