# My Summary Overlays are bad after upgrading to 4.7

Tags: contacts, profile, ui

On two separate sites that were upgraded to 4.7, the "Summary Overlay" function seems to have been uglified.

Specifically - in the past, when hovering over the person icon on the left of many contact listings, you would get a nice little black-background pop-up with additional information about the contact.

Now, those popups are filled with what appears to be a collection of many profiles.

There is a reserved Summary Overlay profile, that I would assume is the only one that should display here.

On a new 4.7 install, I am not seeing this issue.

Am I missing some undocumented configuration, or is this a bug?

Comment: Posted as an issue here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21017

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to have been caused by some sql that was posted as a solution to a different problem, here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18547/233.

If you also ran the bad sql, you can fix it by running the sql command:

```
update civicrm_uf_group set name = 'summary_overlay' where name LIKE 'summary_overlay_%';
```

Specifically, the bug arises because that overlay is generated from a snippet with what should be the summary_overlay profile, but because the name was altered, the overlay is using all available profiles.

Comment: Looks like i had already +1'd this, but actually needed it today on a new inherited site. thx for providing the solution

Comment: I've also recently discovered that other profiles that got renamed may also cause issues, so you might want to look through the other entries in civicrm_uf_group compared with a stock install and fix them also.