# Errors only randomly on admin pages

Tags: error, admin

I'm getting randomly the errors below when I go to an admin page.  They don't always happen.  Any idea what this is?

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sporti62/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/SchemaHandler.php on line 750

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sporti62/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/SchemaHandler.php on line 750

Usually get a bunch of these...

PHP version 5.6.32
CiviCRM 4.7.28
Wordpress 4.9.1

[image]

Comment: relates to an outdated version - can we undo the bumping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in later versions.

Comment: This issue is indeed fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely happen on the page load after you press the "Fix Missing Indices" button on the Administration Status page.  A more permanent automated fix is being worked on, but is fairly difficult.  You can see the [answer here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/how-to-find-and-or-fix-missing-indices) for how to fix this manually if you're SQL-savvy.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the log file.  It seems to disappear after I clear the cache, then after a time working on the system comes back.

Comment: If you follow the instructions on the linked answer, does the problem go away?  Please take a backup (and ideally use a test site) before trying this!

Comment: No the problem does not go away.  I cannot seem to determine the cause.  It happens usually when I connect first time after a long period of time.  Not there for the remainder of my session it seems.  Very weird.

Comment: Anyone out there that can help with this?  Error is still there and the linked answer is not my issue it seems - there are no errors in the log file.  According to the schemahandler.php file, the previous comparison between existing and required indexes failed because there is missing data in the for loop.